# Post username on page

Tags: javascript, html

Is there some way i can do like i can fetch and show text inputs ?

Like this:

```
document.getElementById('input_id')

<input type="text" placeholder="username" id="input_id">
```

and then the output will be like this:

```
document.showElementById('box_id')

<div id="box_id">Welcome + text input</div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('box_id').innerHTML = "Welcome  " + document.getElementById('text_id').value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this:

```
var name = document.getElementById('input_id').value;
document.getElementById('box_id').innerHTML = "Welcome " + name;
```

That's it.

**EDIT**
Checking at your code, it looks that you want to create a `showElementById` method

Trivial, but just in case:

```
function showElementByIds(inputId, divId){
    var name = document.getElementById(inputId).value;
    document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML = "Welcome " + name;
}
```

Then, to use it:

```
showElementByIds('input_id', 'box_id');
```

Cheers

Comment: It doesnt seem to work... I have the script but how will the html look like ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var username = document.getElementById('input_id').value;
document.getElementById('box_id').innerHTML = 'Welcome ' + username;
```